# deletion success message

Tags: word-choice

I want to notify a user when the user has deleted a box successfully.

Original Message

```
Box has been deleted successfully
```

New Message

```
Success to delete the box
```

What is better expression?

Comment: Adding and deleting are complete opposites.

Comment: (Please update your question so that it makes sense.  If you don't want to do that you should delete the question.)

Comment: Sorry, I has been updated my question.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense.

Comment: `Success to` will pretty much never be used in English.  It's one of the many, many, "rules" about which words do or do not combine with which.  `success with`, `in`, `at`, `from` can be used, depending on the total phrase.  probably others too, just not `to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Box has been deleted successfully" is the better choice by far. "Box deleted successfully," or simply "box deleted," would also work.